# Use WFS URL as fieldcalculator command

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, wfs

I am looking for a way to import a WFS layer at the fieldcalculator directly by command.
[image]

The name of the layer in the WFS is "Naturschutzgebiete".

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am working on a greenfield analysis model. In this part of the model i am cutting the layer on a defined area, the next step would be the buffer and so on. But for this part I would like to import the WFS directly to the model function, so I have it updated all the time when I run the model. I know that I could save it as a vector layer but in that way, it wont get updated when I run the model.

Comment: are you sure it won't get updated? the WFS datasource refetches most times

Comment: No, not sure : /. But it seems like there is no way to directly import it to the fieldcalculator so I have to go this way and hope that its updating.